# Why did my branch2 make changes to branch1? in Git

Tags: git, branch, commit

I had a branch validation. I made a commit to it. I realized I wanted to experiment with a possible solution. So, I created a new branch called validation2. I worked on validation2 for thirty minutes and got messy.

I realized that I sort of wasted my time with that experimental solution, so I said to my self, "Eh, let go back to validation and then git branch -D validation2. Get rid of it."

However, something really odd happened. At first, I had switching back to the OG branch called validation. I used this command --> git checkout validation.

I then panicked because I had switched branches many times using that command. I switched to the branch I had thought I was already on: git checkout validation2.

I then had the ability to switch between both branches. I first went to second one and saw my miserable code that I wanted to trash. Then--here is when I was really confused, the noob that I am--when I went back to the original branch called 'validation' the changes I had made in the second one was in there too.

What happened? I had to restore back to a commmit I had made in validation which had the message "built in validation" but all the stuff I did correctly about customizable validation was lost, albeit an hour's work but I thought to myself what if it were much longer?

I know this was more narrative base rather than code base, and any help would help. Here are some questions I have in general.

Should I have committed changes to my customizable validation code to the branch validation before creating validation 2?

If I had done that, then would branch 2 code not have written itself over branch 1?

Answer (score 0):

Despite your efforts to make it as clear as possible, we still lack a lot of information to give you a definitive answer. But:

> Should I have committed changes to my customizable validation code to the branch validation before creating validation 2?

Yes you should, but Git wouldn't have let you switch from a branch to another (then back again) if it was about to overwrite something… unless you've made the mistake to rush into "git checkout **-f**" option, or "git reset **--hard**" from the beginning.

If you did it to force a switch that was prevented by error messages, you may have lost some data. If you did not, there's no reason that would cause such a loss.

Be aware that `git stash` exists when you need to store your recent changes somewhere when you want to check out something, but take the time to practice Git first or you may forget what you stashed and get even more confused.

Try to do `git log --graph validation validation2` as well to have a better idea of how your commits are actually laid in history.

> Then--here is when I was really confused, the noob that I am--when I went back to the original branch called 'validation' the changes I had made in the second one was in there too.

If you didn't use any specific merge commands, there's two reasons that can lead to this situation:

- Either you didn't commit anything on `validation2` and then, both the branches are still pointing to the same place. Since there's nothing to check out, you get the ability to move from a branch to the other one, depending on which one you want to record your next commit on ;
- Or you added your modifications to files that are not tracked yet (never done a `git add` on it yet). Untracked files are left untouched by Git even if they lie in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks. I will commit when before switching to another branch. Thanks for this write up. I would give you a thumbs up, but I don't have enough cred to do so.